# Sum group by multiple columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sum

- I have 2 tables, is the "course" to save the education (including "id_course", "title" - course's name, "credits" - the number credits of course) and the table "takes" save grade of each Student associated vs students sections (including "id_student", "id_course", year, semester, grade- score letters).
- I write 1 procedure to compute score average, accumulated credits of each Period when the input "id_students" such as screen. and run, you have the output 2 Period invalid (2006 - Fall,and  2008 - Spring)

[image: View 2 tables]

[image: Output of My procedure]

Comment: Are there multiple students taking courses in the same semester (Fall 2006 and Spring 2008)?

Comment: Is it possible to write the procedure without including the section table? All the required columns from section table are available in the takes table as well, right?

Comment: Would this query work: SELECT
 t.[year]
 , t.semester
 ,  (SUM(dbo.f_get_grade_number(t.grade) * c.credits) / SUM(c.credits)) AS GPA
 , (SUM(c.credits)) AS Sum_credits_section
FROM student st, takes t, course c
WHERE
 st.ID = @id_student
AND st.ID = t.ID
AND c.course_id = t.course_id
GROUP BY t.semester, t.[year];

Comment: @JosephB: OK. tks. I edited my procedure.